# d3 + leaflet path fill issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, choropleth

I'm working on a timelapsed filled map using Leaflet as a baselayer and a d3 topojson file so I can color in some countries. I used http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/ to get started, and everything was going great until I tried to shade in the Russian Federation. Its landmass spans non-contiguous tiles, and when I try to add a fill style to my #RUS path, it behaves anomalously. Example is here: http://dataviz.du.edu/projects/scratch/study_abroad.html
Example will take 1.5 s to render completely, it shades 3 countries, with the Russian Federation shading last.

This example uses a topojson file that I have used in other, pure d3 projects and have filled #RUS in those contexts without this issue.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This example uses a topojson file that I have used in other, pure d3 projects and have filled #RUS in those contexts without this issue.

You must be mistaken because your TopoJSON file is actually corrupt. See here an example with that file straight from your server: http://plnkr.co/edit/QOTwV3?p=preview Mind that i'm using plain TopoJSON and Leaflet's GeoJSON layer but it's yielding the exact same results.

PS. Is there any reason as to why you're using D3 for this? Asking because what i see you doing can be done just using Leaflet and TopoJSON, without D3. Here's a simple example:

```
function delay(features) {
  var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
    style: getStyle,
  }).addTo(map);
  var delay = 100;
  features.forEach(function(feature) {
    delay = delay + 100;
    setTimeout(function() {
      geojsonLayer.addData(feature);
    }, delay);
  });
}

var url = 'http://crossorigin.me/http://dataviz.du.edu/projects/scratch/worldnew.json';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var geojsonData = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.test);
  delay(geojsonData.features);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. No, there wasn't a good reason to use D3 in this situation. I am more familiar with d3 than with leaflet, so I appreciate the pointer that I could do this without D3.